# Trouble with changing owner group of a windows shared folder from root to pi

Tags: pi-3, linux, raspbian-stretch, permissions

I have mounted a windows shared folder to a raspberry pi directory using

sudo mount.cifs ip_address_windows_machine/folderpath  /home/pi/shared_folder -o user=MY_USERNAME,password=MY_PASSWORD

The owner group for the shared_folder changes to root:root after the above command. How can I avoid that, I need the owner group of the /home/pi/shared_folder to be pi:pi only.

I have tried sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/shared_folder after mounting. But the owner group doesn't change from root to pi. Please suggest a method to change the owner group from root to pi after mounting the common folder(from windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the uid/gid options **when mounting the share** you can't do it after mounting, because you can't actually change the owenership (that doesn't make sense to a windows share)

```
sudo mount.cifs <remotetarget> <dir> -o uid=pi,gid=pi,user=<username>,pass=<password>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I wish I could up vote your answer, but I've got <15 reputation points.